# Why does only one Node readline object work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

In the following node.js example I want to ask the user for two numbers and then return the sum back to the console. I have used readline.question() twice (one for each number) but the user is asked only for the second number. Why does the first console prompt not appear?

```
const readline = require('readline');

let firstNumber = 0;
let secondNumber = 0;

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Your first number: ', (answer) => {
    firstNumber = parseInt(answer);
    rl.close();
});

const r2 = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

r2.question('Your second number: ', (answer) => {
    secondNumber = parseInt(answer);
    console.log(`The sum of these numbers is: ${secondNumber + firstNumber}`);
    r2.close();
});
```

Comment: It seems that both r1 and r2 are running at the same time. If I input a number it appears twice in the console, as if I've held the key down for too long, and the result is double the intended input. Eg, I hit '1' but '11' appears and the result is 2.

Comment: You cannot ask two questions at the same time. Put the second question in the callback of the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to wait for the first question to get answered, you need to ask the second one after the answer comes back, like this:

```
const readline = require('readline');

let firstNumber = 0;
let secondNumber = 0;

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});
rl.question('Your first number: ', (answer) => {
    firstNumber = parseInt(answer);
    rl.question('Your second number: ', (answer) => {
        secondNumber = parseInt(answer);
        console.log(`The sum of these numbers is: ${secondNumber + firstNumber}`);
        rl.close();
    });
});
```

Functions that take time in javascript are scheduled and the interpreter continues.

If you want something to happen after something else, you need to do it in a callback or promise.then mechanism.

You'll get the hang of it.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense! There is just one more bug now at the second r1.quesiton: (your 4th line): `ReferenceError: r1 is not defined`

Comment: I didn't include all of your code, just the piece to show you how to put the second question in the callback.  You still need the bit to set up the readline interface.

Comment: up'ed. But Imagine chaining 40 questions - it's an unsustainable structure. Alternatively the callback could be a common "dispatching function" that evaluates answers and calls the questions. Each question a separate function of course.

Comment: Agreed. OP has a lot to learn and it's not bad to start at the basic concept of how callbacks work.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a race condition? `question` appears to be an async function so it’s plausible that by the time the first instance attempts to write to the output stream the second instance has paused it.

You don’t really need two instances, wait for the response from the first question and then prompt for the second in the callback from the first e.g.

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Your first number: ', ans1 => {
  first = parseInt(ans1);
  rl.question('Your second number: ', ans2 => {
    second = parseInt(ans2);
    console.log(`The sum of these numbers is: ${second + first}`);
    rl.close();
  });
});
```